# how to create ellipse inside 3d matrix?

Tags: c, matrix, ellipse

I have a AxBxC matrix filled with 0 and need to make an ellipse inside. The area that it covers needs to b filled with 1.

I have the code to create the 3d matrix, but don't know how to do the ellipse.

The user needs to give all the matrix dimensions and the ellipse dimensions as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void criaMatriz() // Function to create 3d matrix
{
  int ***m;
  int x, y, z, i, j, k;

  // Number of lines
  printf("Digite o número de linhas:");
  scanf("%d", &y);

  // Number of columns
  printf("Digite o número de colunas:");
  scanf("%d", &z);

  // depth
  printf("Digite a largura do paralelepipedo:");
  scanf("%d", &x);
    
  m = malloc(x * sizeof(int **));

  for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
  {
    m[i] = malloc(y * sizeof(int *));
  }

  for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < y; j++)
    {
      m[i][j] = malloc(z * sizeof(int));
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < y; j++)
    {
      for (k = 0; k < z; k++)
      {
        m[i][j][k] = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < y; j++)
    {
      for (k = 0; k < z; k++)
      {
        printf("%2d ", m[i][j][k]);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < y; j++)
    {
      free(m[i][j]);
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
  {
    free(m[i]);
  }

  free(m);
}

int main()
{

  criaMatriz();
  return 0;
}
```

I tried making a sphere first, but it didn't work.

Comment: What's the maximum values that `x`, `y` & `z` can take? Where are the ellipse dimensions? Use `char` instead of `int` as you're only using to store `0` or `1`. You can further go down to bits, but one step at a time. Also, technically Ellipse in 3D is called Ellipsoid.

Comment: `I tried making a sphere first, but it didn't work.` Well, where is that code?